# clojure.spec coll-of alternative types

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I'm using clojure.spec to validate a vector of map-entries. The vector looks like:

```
[{:point {:x 30 :y 30}}
 {:point {:x 34 :y 33}}
 {:user "joe"}]
```

I'd like to structure the spec to require 1..N `::point` entries and only a single `::user` entry.

Here is my (unsuccessful) attempt at structuring this spec:

```
(s/def ::coord (s/and number? #(>= % 0)))
(s/def ::x ::coord)
(s/def ::y ::coord)
(s/def ::point (s/keys :req-un [::x ::y]))
(s/def ::user (s/and string? seq))

(s/def ::vector-entry (s/or ::pt ::user))
(s/def ::my-vector (s/coll-of ::vector-entry :kind vector))
```

When I run just the validation of one `::point` entry, it works:

```
spec> (s/valid? ::point {:point {:x 0 :y 0}})
true
spec> (s/valid? ::my-vector [{:point {:x 0 :y 0}}])
false
```

Any ideas on how to structure the `s/or` part so the vector entries can be of either `::user` or `::point` types?

Also, any ideas on how to require one and only one `::user` entry and 1..N `::point` entries in the vector?

Comment: Is the shape actually 1..n points, then 1 user -- or can the user be anywhere?

Comment: You may be interested in reading https://twitter.com/stuarthalloway/status/876087016219451392

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a possible spec for the data in your question:

```
(require '[clojure.spec.alpha :as s])

(s/def ::coord nat-int?)
(s/def ::x ::coord)
(s/def ::y ::coord)
(s/def ::xy (s/keys :req-un [::x ::y]))
(s/def ::point (s/map-of #{:point} ::xy))
(s/def ::username (s/and string? seq))
(s/def ::user (s/map-of #{:user} ::username))

(s/def ::vector-entry (s/or :point ::point :user ::user))
(s/def ::my-vector (s/coll-of ::vector-entry :kind vector))

(s/valid? ::point {:point {:x 0 :y 0}})
(s/valid? ::my-vector [{:point {:x 0 :y 0}}])
(s/valid? ::my-vector [{:point {:x 0 :y 0}} {:user "joe"}])
```

A few observations:

- An `or` spec requires that specs be given names.
- The labelling of the different items by type `:point` or `:user` necessitates a level of indirection, I used `map-of` on the top and `keys` for the nested level but there are many choices
- The small errors in your specs could be caught early by [trying each subform at the REPL](http://blog.cognitect.com/blog/2017/6/5/repl-debugging-no-stacktrace-required).
- In this case the relative difficulty of specing the data is a hint that this data shape will be inconvenient for programs, too. Why force a program to do an O(N) search when you know `:user` is required?

Hope this helps!

Comment: Does this have the constraint that there be "one and only one `::user` entry"? I don't see where that's done.

Comment: No, this is just getting things past the minor errors. If the answer to my question about data shape is "I really need this shape" I would recommend adding a predicate function over the conformed data

Answer (score 4):

While Stuart's answer is very instructive and solves *many* of your problems, I don't think it covers your criteria of ensuring "one and only one `::user` entry."

Riffing off his answer:

```
(s/def ::coord nat-int?)
(s/def ::x ::coord)
(s/def ::y ::coord)
(s/def ::xy (s/keys :req-un [::x ::y]))
(s/def ::point (s/map-of #{:point} ::xy))
(s/def ::username (s/and string? seq))
(s/def ::user (s/map-of #{:user} ::username))

(s/def ::vector-entry (s/or :point ::point 
                            :user ::user))
(s/def ::my-vector (s/and (s/coll-of ::vector-entry
                                     :kind vector)
                          (fn [entries]
                            (= 1
                               (count (filter (comp #{:user}
                                                    key)
                                              entries))))))

(s/valid? ::point {:point {:x 0 :y 0}})
;; => true
(s/valid? ::my-vector [{:point {:x 0 :y 0}}])
;; => false
(s/valid? ::my-vector [{:point {:x 0 :y 0}}
                       {:user "joe"}])
;; => true
(s/valid? ::my-vector [{:point {:x 0 :y 0}}
                       {:point {:x 1 :y 1}}
                       {:user "joe"}])
;; => true
(s/valid? ::my-vector [{:point {:x 0 :y 0}}
                       {:user "joe"}
                       {:user "frank"}])
;; => false
```

The important addition is in the spec for `::my-vector`. Note that the conformed output of `s/or` is a map entry, and that is what is passed to the new custom predicate.

I should note that, while this works, it adds yet another linear scan to your validation. Unfortunately, I don't know if spec provides a good way to do it in a single pass.

Answer (score 2):

The answers by Tim and Stuart solved the issue and were very informative. I would like to point out that there is also a feature of Clojure spec which can be used to specify structure for the vector of points and a user.

Namely, spec allows to use regular expressions to specify sequences. For more information see [the Spec guide](https://clojure.org/guides/spec#_sequences).

Below is a solution using specs for sequences. This builds on the previous solutions.

```
(require '[clojure.spec.alpha :as s])

(s/def ::coord nat-int?)
(s/def ::x ::coord)
(s/def ::y ::coord)
(s/def ::xy (s/keys :req-un [::x ::y]))
(s/def ::point (s/map-of #{:point} ::xy))
(s/def ::username (s/and string? seq))
(s/def ::user (s/map-of #{:user} ::username))

(s/def ::my-vector (s/cat :points-before (s/* ::point)
                          :user ::user
                          :points-after (s/* ::point)))

(s/valid? ::point {:point {:x 0 :y 0}})
;; => true
(s/valid? ::my-vector [{:point {:x 0 :y 0}}])
;; => false
(s/valid? ::my-vector [{:point {:x 0 :y 0}}
                       {:user "joe"}])
;; => true
(s/valid? ::my-vector [{:point {:x 0 :y 0}}
                       {:point {:x 1 :y 1}}
                       {:user "joe"}])
;; => true
(s/valid? ::my-vector [{:point {:x 0 :y 0}}
                       {:user "joe"}
                       {:user "frank"}])
;; => false
(s/valid? ::my-vector [{:point {:x 0 :y 0}}
                       {:user "joe"}
                       {:point {:x 1 :y 1}}])
;; => true
```

This can be easily adapted if the `::user` entry is required at the end.

Comment: This is the best answer IMO. I had a sneaky feeling that there was a better way to clearly express the intent with spec. +1